# Random sample from multiple columns

Tags: r, function, text, dplyr, sample

I have a dataset including multiple columns, where each row represents a product and each column includes one comment on the respective product. For each product, we observe multiple comments, each stored in its own column.

Now I want to create two new datasets in the following way:
(1) a dataset with only one column, including a random sample of x (number of) comments out of multiple comment columns.
(2) as (1), but now I want to sample the same number of comments from each column (e.g., 2 comments from "comment1" and 2 comments from "comment2".

```
Example data:
commentda = data.frame(product_id = c(1,2,3,4), comment1 = c("Very good", "Bad", "Would buy it", "Zero stars"), comment2 = c("Bad reputation", "Good seller", "Great service", "I will buy it again"))
> 
> commentda
  product_id     comment1            comment2
1          1    Very good      Bad reputation
2          2          Bad         Good seller
3          3 Would buy it       Great service
4          4   Zero stars I will buy it again
```

Comment: Your "question" doesn't contain neither any question nor code to help you with so far. You may want to update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may get the data in long format which will help to do such operations efficiently.

```
library(dplyr)
n <- 2

long_data <- commentda %>%  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('comment'))
```

1. To include random `n` comments

```
long_data %>% slice_sample(n = n)
```

2. To include random `n` comments from each column.

```
long_data %>%  group_by(name) %>%  slice_sample(n = n)
```

Comment: Thanks! Is slice_sample a dplyr function? I tried ??slice_sample
 but R tells me it found no results.

Comment: Yes, it is available in `dplyr` 1.0.0 onwards. If you have an older version you can use `sample_n` i.e `sample_n(size = n)`